# Executing a javascript function returned from AJAX response (PHP)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to load a javascript function once Ajax has returned the HTML code through PHP. This requires me to echo the javascript in the ajax response.

In other words i am trying to add this code (placed between script tags) in the PHP Ajax response.. hoping that it executes

```
$('#green').smartpaginator({ Some code... });
```

From what I have read so far the browser has done reading the Javascript and will not execute this. Is there a way to do this.... ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to Evaluate that code like this

```
eval("("+response+")");
```

**OR**

If your response contains both html and javascript code you have to do like this

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "/snippets/js-in-ajax-response.html",
            context: document.body,
            success: function(responseText) {
                $("#response-div").html(responseText);
                $("#response-div").find("script").each(function(i) {
                    eval($(this).text());
                });
            }
        });
```