# jquery load doesn't work in loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax

Seeing some weird behavior and I'm completely stumped. I've got an index page that looks like this:

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="about.htm">About</a></li>
</nav>
<main><main>

<script>
$('nav li a').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
  $('main').load(this.href)
})
</script>
```

In "about.htm" I have the following:

```
<footer>
<a href="privacy.htm">Privacy</a>
</footer>

<script>
$('footer a').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$('main').load(this.href)
})
</script>
```

When you click the "About" link in the nav, about.htm loads into main as expected. But when you click the "Privacy" link in the footer, it doesn't load into main, it loads a new page. The script is exactly the same, so why is this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681072/executing-a-javascript-function-returned-from-ajax-response-php

Comment: I don't completely understand that post, but I don't think that's the issue. If I add an extra div to my index page, and change the footer link script to load into that, it works. And any other functions contained in external pages work fine, just not that one. It's as if you can't load things into the same container from two different places.