# It's Possible to Simulate html btn click in PHP ?

Tags: php

It's Possible to Simulate html btn click in PHP like in Jquery?

```
$('input[value=Submit]').click();
```

without use:

```
 echo '<script>.....</script>';
```

Comment: No, because PHP doesn't run at the place where buttons are clicked. It runs at the place that makes the buttons.

Comment: I can get all the data from page in this command : 
$html = file_get_html($url);

Comment: It doesn't matter. By the time you see the page, PHP has long ago finished running. You can use Javascript to make a button click which causes _another request_ to the webserver to go through and run _some more_ PHP, but you cannot use PHP to click a button because browsers don't run PHP.

Comment: The problem is when i call to script by Ajax, only the part of php is working the part of jquery not.

Comment: Then there's your issue, what is the code there that is not working, and what is it that you want it to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369413/run-php-with-jquery-in-ajax-call?noredirect=1#comment69940483_41369413

Answer (score 0):

no It will better use in javascript

when you hover then your form submit.

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("form").click();}

Comment: <p>when you hover on submit button then click event occurred.</p>

<form>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" onmouseover="myFunction()" >
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("submit").click();
}
</script>

Comment: Can't i must to go the page in Ajax call. and there only php is working for me. i dont know why

Answer (score 0):

No. Php is a 
[server side language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side). It means that it runs before your html, css and javascript ( also known as [client side languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_scripting) ) are loaded. So, you can't capture a button click event with php. The correct approach for this is using javascript.

Comment: the problem is jquery dosnt work in the page was i use in AJAX call

Comment: Did you load it correctly? Do you have more details?

Comment: Yes, i describe the code details in this post : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369413/run-php-with-jquery-in-ajax-call?noredirect=1#comment69940483_41369413

Comment: I think this will solve your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681072/executing-a-javascript-function-returned-from-ajax-response-php

Comment: thank you for the reply,
this code what he describe in the post is correct, but not solve our issue
because the jquery script must run on same page with php.

Comment: Oh, i get it now. Well, try editing your js to this:

<script src="../../../../../Scripts/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[value=Submit]').click();
  
});
</script>

Should get the job done ;)

Comment: Still don't work :( ,the problem is the ajax print this line and not perform

Comment: You think it's possible ?

Comment: try changing the dataType: 'text', to dataType: 'html' in your ajax. Tell me what happens

Comment: maybe ajax grab the js script and think is a back answer from php ?