# how to make js open a new window from a link created by a php file?

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have html canvas which saves images and add it to sql database using this code

```
//****************************************************************
// Example function save save canvas content into image file.
// www.permadi.com
//****************************************************************
//var testCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var postData = "canvasData="+canvasData;
    //var debugConsole= document.getElementById("debugConsole");
    //debugConsole.value=canvasData;

//  alert("canvasData ="+canvasData );
    alert("wait please" );
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST",'/wp-includes/pluggable.php',true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'canvas/upload');
    //ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-TypeLength', postData.length);
ajax.send(postData);
//ajax.send(person);//send name

    ajax.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4)
        {
            alert(ajax.responseText);
            // Write out the filename.
            //  document.getElementById("debugFilenameConsole").innerHTML=" <br><a target='_blank' href='"+ajax.responseText+"'>"+ajax.responseText+"</a><br>Reload this page to generate new image or click the filename to open the image file.";
        }
    }

    ajax.send(postData);




///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

}
```

which calls pluggable.php and the php file creates a link 
i tried to let the php to open new window using

```
window.location.assign('http://www.sktcho.com/?p=$row_id');
```

but it never worksand also the header type of solution

now i tink that js has to take the link created from php and open in in a new window but i couldn't do it! any help?

Answer (score -1):

May be you can try like this.Echo the js code from php file

**Write this code in PHP file**

```
echo "window.location.assign('http://www.sktcho.com/?p=".$row_id."');"
```

and when ajax response comes you can try the js code

**Write this code in JS file**

```
eval("("+responseText+")");
```

thanks to [this ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11681104/6613333) for eval solution.